# Getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS on 32 bit iOS devices using unity 5.1.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, unity-game-engine, exc-bad-access

I am getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal on _view.layer.bounds.size in createWithWindow method in DisplayManager.mm class.This crash is only on iOS 32 bit devices.The code is working fine for all 64 bit devices.I have used unity 5.1.1 to build the project.Please find below the code:

```
- (void)createWithWindow:(UIWindow*)window andView:(UIView*)view
{
_window = window;
_view   = view;

if (_view) {

    CGSize layerSize = _view.layer.bounds.size;
    screenSize = CGSizeMake(roundf(layerSize.width) * view.contentScaleFactor, roundf(layerSize.height) * _view.contentScaleFactor);
}
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use CGSizeMake(CGFloat width, CGFloat height) ?

Comment: @blackforestcowboy This code is generated by unity itself.I think the problem is with _view i.e. UnityView. Anyways,I used CGSizeMake too.The problem is still the same.